# Executing python module through popen from a python script/shell

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python module that is executed by the following command:

```
python3 -m moduleName args
```

Trying to execute it from a script using subprocess.popen.

```
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Based on subprocess documentation, we are recommended to pass a sequence rather than a string. So when I try to pass the below command as the argument

```
command = ['python3','-m','moduleName','args']
```

I end up getting a python shell instead of the module being executed. If I pass it as a string, things are working as expected.  I'm not able to find documentation or references for this.

Can someone please help throw some light into this behavior?
What would be the best way to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this on windows by any chance?

Comment: I'm running it on a debian based linux.

Comment: Do you really need `shell=True, text=True`? Is there a particular reason you are not importing this module instead?

Comment: Actually using an external library that are passing these arguments by default. Do you think that will play a role in the above scenario?

Comment: Ran an experiment by removing shell=True and things worked!! 
Is there an explanation as to why it would work without this attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the `shell=True` option. When `Popen` runs in shell mode (under POSIX), the command is appended to the shell command after a "-c" option ([`subprocess.py`, Python 3.9](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/subprocess.py#L1686)):

```
args = [unix_shell, "-c"] + args
```

When the list of arguments is expanded, the first argument after '-c' (in your case, 'python3') is treated as the parameter to '-c'. The other arguments are interpreted as further arguments to the `unix_shell` command. The `-m`, for example, activates job control in bash, as outlined [in the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin).

The solution is to either

- pass the command as a single string, as you did, or
- do not set the `shell` option for `Popen`, which is a good idea anyway, as it is lighter on resources and avoids pitfalls like the one you encountered.

Comment: On the same note.. Can you please help with reference/man page for -m flag that activates job control in bash?

Comment: @Maverickgugu Added a link to the relevant part of the _bash_ manual.